# drawRect gets called on UIView subclass but not on UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My code is working so far but I had to create a Class for the `UIView`. This is a bit inconvenient because I need to interact with the ViewController too.

BTW, I did try `[self setNeedsDisplay]` on the `ViewDidLoad` of the `UIViewController` subclass file but it didn't work.

Here's the code, which works on `UIView` Subclass but doesn't get called on a `UIViewController` one:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    someNum = 1;
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 40);
    [self addDotImageX:30 andY:40];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Any ideas on what to try? BTW, this is a TabBar App. I know those can somehow block the calls to `drawRect`.

The Tabs where created programatically, not through a Nib. Eg:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc;

vc = [[Education alloc] init];
vc.title = @"Education";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
vc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
[vc release];
```

I would appreciate any ideas. I've been through the answers on this site related to `setNeedsDisplay` not calling `drawRect` and haven't found an answer for my particular case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing up two classes. A UIViewController is not a UIView, meaning it doesn't inherits from UIView. But the good news is it [has a view, declared as property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW2): It's composition. The drawRect method is only available in a UIView class/subclass.

If you like to force the controller's view to redraw you can call

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

in the viewController.

You can set your own custom view as the view of your viewController with the [loadView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1) method. It could look like this:

```
- (void)loadView
{  
    MySubclassOfUIView *rootView = [[MySubclassOfUIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // do more view configuration ...

    self.view = rootView;
    [rootView release];
}
```

So you can keep your drawing code separated in your MySubclassOFUIView.m file.

About the **[UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**:

> The UIViewController class provides
>   the fundamental view-management model
>   for iPhone applications. The basic
>   view controller class supports the
>   presentation of an associated view,
>   support for managing modal views, and
>   support for rotating views in response
>   to device orientation changes.

And the purpose of a **[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)**:

> The UIView class defines a rectangular
>   area on the screen and the interfaces
>   for managing the content in that area.
>   At runtime, a view object handles the
>   rendering of any content in its area
>   and also handles any interactions with
>   that content.

Have a look at [Cocoa Core Competencies / Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) in Apple's official documentation, it describes the MVC design pattern.

Comment: I appologize, I didn't phrase my question propertly but still, you gave me the answer. I do know UIVIew and UIViewcontroller are different classes and that UIViewController has it's own view. It's just that, for some reason, on all the examples I found everyone was using: [self setNeedsDisplay];. Adding the view, of course, made all the difference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: All good, I just didn't know if you've got the big picture so I had to get into some detail.

Comment: @NickWeaver : your answer, enlighten me! Thanks. I was just about thinking how do you override a drawRect view, when what you use is NSViewController

Answer (score 2):

You can't override `drawRect` in a UIViewController, because UIViewController doesn't have a `drawRect` method.

As I understand, you're making some custom drawing, so it's ok for you to subclass UIView (though if you can have the same results without doing so, it's better). But then if you want to control its behavior, then you should subclass UIViewController.

Make sure you understand how [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) works!

Comment: I think you mean 'property'? Anyway, no, you can't. Like Nick just pointed out, you are mixing up two classes! Overriding a method only works when inheriting a base class that has that method.

Comment: Ok, deleted that comment. My bad... in a way. You can't call drawRect PROPERTY on UIViewController but you can call it FROM it. Am I right now, professor? ;-) I understand the differences between a View and a Controller. I just have a hard time with the language since I'm kind of new to it. Please bare with me.

Comment: It's ok, you'll get used to it. :) Make sure you understand how Inheritance and Polymorphism work in OOP... I think you're mistaking some basic concepts here.

Answer (score 1):

Set your class's class which has been inherited from `UIViewController` in the interface builder
class which is inherited from `UIView` and don't override the `-drawRect:` method in the class which has been inherited from `UIViewController`.  Define the `-drawRect:` method in the class which has been subclassed from `UIView`.